# Show/hide div shows the bottom of the exposed div

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I have a page with two divs, one hidden and one displayed. When I click on a link at the bottom of the page, I want the hidden div to display and the displayed div to be hidden. It works fine, but if the browser height is small (e.g., on a mobile device) the user sees the div that gets displayed scrolled all the way to the bottom.

Here is the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display()
{
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display="none";
}
</script>

<!-- Start of content -->
  <div id="div1" style="display:block">
    <h2>This is shown at the beginning</h2>
    <p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p>
    <a rel="external" href="bogus.tar.gz" onclick="display(); return true">Click here</a>
  </div>

  <div id="div2" style="display:none">
  <h2>This is shown later</h2>
    <p>Goodbye</p><p>Goodbye</p><p>Goodbye</p><p>Goodbye</p><p>Goodbye</p><p>Goodbye</p>
    <p>Goodbye</p><p>Goodbye</p><p>Goodbye</p>
  </div>
```

If I put the link at the *top* of the page, the problem goes away, but the flow of the page demands that the link be at the bottom of the page.

So how can I get the browser to show the *top* of the div once it gets displayed.

Comment: Is this consistent on all mobile browsers? Which ones did you test on?

Comment: Are the 2 divs identical in height? If so, try using `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.scrollTo(x, y)
```

If you want to scroll the page to the top use

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0)
```

Otherwise, change the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

hide the div1 before displaying the div2.

If it does not run, use a scrollto javascript (based on displayed div) call to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('div2').scrollTop=0
```

Comment: For some reason, this one did not work. However avetarman's suggestion did work.